# jQuery loop through object and look for title but skip others

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table, skip

I have been teaching myself JS and Jquery and I still struggle with how to effectively use $ to loop through an object and extract the info I want.

I have  a table that has a flag icon and a title describing that I want to put at end of the row.  However, there are sometimes other icons that I must ignore.  So I look for "flag" in url and if it exist I set innerHTML of 2nd to last cell to 'title'.

As you can see below I have had to create a decrement VAR y to keep from skipping to next row with "title" if I encounter non flag icon.

I want this row to be appended with "title" which is the location:

```
<td>11:44pm</td><td><a href="/stats/visitors?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;country=the+united+states"></a></td><td> <a class="custom" title="Comcast Cable" href="/stats/visitors?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;ip_address=75.70.103.23">Comcast Cable</a></td><td><a href="/stats/visitors-actions?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;session_id=228613269">1 action</a></td><td>10s</td><td width="100%"> &nbsp; </td><td></td>
```

To look like this:

```
<td>11:44pm</td><td><a href="/stats/visitors?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;country=the+united+states"></a></td><td> <a class="custom" title="Comcast Cable" href="/stats/visitors?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;ip_address=75.70.103.23">Comcast Cable</a></td><td><a href="/stats/visitors-actions?site_id=66351439&amp;date=2011-04-27&amp;session_id=228613269">1 action</a></td><td>10s</td><td width="100%">Aurora, CO, USA</td><td></td>
```

So my question - What is a better way to do this whole procedure.  Here is a link to the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ukJxH/78/  - at 3:47 you can see a non flag icon.

```
var x = $('.tableborder tr img');
y = 1;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var flagg = x[i].src;
    var pattn = /flag/gi;
    var loca = x[i].title;

    if (flagg.match(pattn) == "flag") {
        //$('td:nth-child(6)')[i + 14 + y].innerHTML = loca;
        $('#main :nth-child(i) td:nth-child(6)')[i].innerHTML = loc } else {
    y = y - 1;
}
```

}

Comment: I see flag icon on every item. What is wrong? (In your jsfiddle, the css have a lot of NON css code like as html, js and warnings from firebug)

Comment: my solution seems like it is too complicated.  The main issue is that there are non flag icons that i must skip over and i am doing that by looking at the src for "flag" and if flag then i set inner html to 'title'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand your question too well. However, the following selector will give you all the flags in the table

```
$('.tableborder tr img[src*="flag"]').each(function(){
   $(this)
    .closest('td')
    .nextAll('td:last')
    .html('Title from image : ' + $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

This should give you a chance to traverse the DOM and get at what you need

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/ukJxH/87/

Comment: That shortens it up a bit - Thanks.  BUt what is best way then put title into cell at end of table in the referrer column?

Comment: @7null, oh is that what you wanted? I've updated my code. Once it finds an image, it will go up the DOM tree till it hits a TD then it will look for the last TD and put the title of the image in the last cell. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: That's perfect - thank you.  I can usually hack my way through it but i want to learn now to determine best/elegant methodology.  Probably kind of hard to do since this is not my day job but more of a hobby.

Comment: @7null no problem :)  a good place to start is going through the selectors list at api.jquery.com. They have a lot! Makes it very easy to find things

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

For example:

```
$(".tableborder tr img").each(function() {
   var src = $(this).attr("src");
   var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a css class to select only the img Tags you're interested in:

```
$(".tableborder tr img.flagImg").each(function() {
   ...
});
```

HTML would then be

```
<img title="Arvada, CO, USA" class="flagImg" src="http://static.getclicky.com/media/flags/us.gif">
```